# Apache (not browser) is caching my file

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, cache

The browser is not caching it. It gets the response headers:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:425169
Content-Type:application/javascript
Date:Thu, 09 Mar 2017 20:06:53 GMT
Expires:Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified:Thu, 09 Mar 2017 20:06:49 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/5.4.16
```

My settings in Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory "/webapps/apps/devsite">
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
    </Directory>
    DocumentRoot /webapps/apps/devsite
    ServerName testing.devsite.com
    SSLEngine off
</VirtualHost>
```

My .htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
FileETag None
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

***The following loads a new, non-cached version:***

1. on the server run: `rm -f /webapps/apps/devsite/scripts/script.js`
2. Reload in the web browser (thus getting a 404)
3. Copy the file back on to server
4. Reload in browser

***The following does loads an old, CACHED version!:***

1. On the server run: `rm -f /webapps/apps/devsite/scripts/script.js`
2. Copy the file back on to server *NOTE: I did not reload in browser yet)*
3. Reload in browser

This shows that Apache is somehow caching it until it gets a new request and cannot find it. Why? How do i fix this?

Comment: Have you had a look to your browser console? May be some settings is overriding headers cache control...

Comment: @sgargel It's not.

Comment: Some apache caching settings seems enabled by default http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472528/apache-caching-images

Answer (score 1):

The issue was it was using the kernel's SendFile which caused it to miss the file being changed. Adding the following fixes it:

```
EnableSendfile off
```

(the "file" is lowercase)

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#enablesendfile

Comment: How can this possibly affect caching?

Comment: @OskarSkog It's because it's a shared folder/network-drive and the server is in a virtural machine